# card game drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery

> Can someone play this game and explain to me why the `.correct.length` class in line 102 is equal to 1?. I put an alert box on it to confirm the length. 
>   Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6haMV/141/

```js
$(init);

function init() {

  $('#element_1').data('number', 1).attr('id', 'card' + 1).draggable({
    containment: '#content',
    stack: '#cardPile div',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    revert: true

  });

  $('#element_2').data('number', 2).attr('id', 'card' + 2).draggable({
    containment: '#content',
    stack: '#cardPile div',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    revert: true
  });

  $('#element_3').data('number', 3).attr('id', 'card' + 3).draggable({
    containment: '#content',
    stack: '#cardPile div',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    revert: true
  });

  $('#element_4').data('number', 4).attr('id', 'card' + 4).draggable({
    containment: '#content',
    stack: '#cardPile div',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    revert: true
  });

  $('#element_5').data('number', 5).attr('id', 'card' + 5).draggable({
    containment: '#content',
    stack: '#cardPile div',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    revert: true
  });

  $('#element_6').data('number', 6).attr('id', 'card' + 6).draggable({
    containment: '#content',
    stack: '#cardPile div',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    revert: true
  });


  $('#slot_1').data('number', 1).droppable({
    accept: '#cardPile div',
    hoverClass: 'hovered',
    drop: handleCardDrop

  });

  $('#slot_2').data('number', 2).droppable({
    accept: '#cardPile div',
    hoverClass: 'hovered',
    drop: handleCardDrop
  });

  $('#slot_3').data('number', 3).droppable({
    accept: '#cardPile div',
    hoverClass: 'hovered',
    drop: handleCardDrop
  });

  $('#slot_4').data('number', 4).droppable({
    accept: '#cardPile div',
    hoverClass: 'hovered',
    drop: handleCardDrop
  });

  $('#slot_5').data('number', 5).droppable({
    accept: '#cardPile div',
    hoverClass: 'hovered',
    drop: handleCardDrop
  });

  $('#slot_6').data('number', 6).droppable({
    accept: '#cardPile div',
    hoverClass: 'hovered',
    drop: handleCardDrop
  });

}

var totalCards = $('#cardPile').children().length;
var totalMatches = 0;

function handleCardDrop(event, ui) {
  var slotNumber = $(this).data('number');
  var cardNumber = ui.draggable.data('number');

  if (slotNumber == cardNumber) {
    totalMatches++;
    ui.draggable.addClass('correct');
    ui.draggable.draggable('disable');
    alert("the .correct length is " + $(".correct").length);
    $(this).droppable('disable');
    ui.draggable.position({
      of: $(this),
      my: 'left top',
      at: 'left top'
    });
    ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);
  }

  if (totalMatches == totalCards) {
    $('#basicModal').modal('show');
  }
}
```

```css
@charset"utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  margin: 30px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  color: #333;
}
#content {
  margin: 80px 70px;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
/* Header/footer boxes */

.wideBox {
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ebedf2;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
.wideBox h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 20px;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
#cardSlots {
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
}
#cardPile {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#cardPile {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 20px;
}
#cardSlots {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 1000px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: normal;
}
#cardSlots div,
#cardPile div {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  background: #fff;
}
#cardSlots div:first-child,
#cardPile div:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
#cardSlots div.hovered {
  background: #aaa;
}
#cardSlots div {
  border: 1px dashed #333;
}
#cardPile div {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #005575;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.3;
}
#cardPile div.ui-draggable-dragging {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  box-shadow: 0 0 .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
#card1.correct {
  background: #5fcf80;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content" class="content">
  <!-- Modal -->

  <div id="cardPile">
    <div id="element_1">Card 1</div>
    <div id="element_2">Card 2</div>
    <div id="element_3">Card 3</div>
  </div>
  <div id="cardSlots">
    <div id="slot_1"></div>
    <div id="slot_2"></div>
    <div id="slot_3"></div>
  </div>
</div>


<!--Modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="textModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align:center">Great Work!</h4>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">Everything was matched :)</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <a href="www.google.com">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No need to be sorry, my apologies if I appeared curt! Thank you for editing and improving your question :)

Comment: uhm do you perhaps know the answer?

Comment: Having further edited your question (including the external resources) you'll see that there's a reported error in the console (as there was on the JS Fiddle hosted demo). I'm not sure if that's the whole of the problem, but fixing that error might well be a step towards making the code work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code **$(".correct").length**  tells the number of element on the DOM having the class selector .correct. when you drop one box then on one element the class is present , when you drop 2 then number of elements increased to 2 and so on....

Comment: can you add an element? and make it two each drop?. Because I dont quite get what you are saying, sorry.

Comment: so the number of element on the dom is only 1?

Comment: At the start of the play there is no element (Div) which has the class "correct". if you run the script $(".correct").length result will be 0. When you drag the div card1  into the slot , the class correct is added on this div. "card1". Now if you run the script $(".correct").length it will result in 1

Comment: everytime a div is dragged to the empty slot, the class will be applied on the div and thus the result of $(".correct").length will keep on increasing

Comment: you mean this one? <div id="element_1">Card 1</div> so if you drag a card it will going to be like <div id="element_1" class="correct">Card 1</div> ?

Comment: why is there no div at start? do you mean html doesnt get load first? sorry I'm slow. please bear with me

Comment: the div is there but it does not have the class correct.

Comment: Nope, $(".correct").length will count the number of elements with class ".correct" on the page. At the start of the game it is 0, ad with each div dropped on the slot it increases.

Comment: why do you think it should be 8 ??

Comment: . c o r r e c t   its 8 letters right? i remember when i used .length using javascript it counts the letters.

Comment: nope its not counting the length of the string "correct" but it is looking for the elements on the page which have the class "correct".

Comment: whats the diff? because it has a $()?

Comment: yes, when you do $() , you are using the Jquery selector and it looks for the elements on the page which matches the selector.